# How to enable partitioning in oracle 12c (docker image)

Tags: oracle, docker

I installed https://hub.docker.com/r/sath89/oracle-12c/ and I have a little problem. I don't know how to enable partitioning in this image. Is it possible? How can I do that?

```
select * from v$option where parameter='Partitioning';
```

returns

```
PARAMETER    |VALUE |CON_ID |
-------------|------|-------|
Partitioning |FALSE |0      |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and its seems that we have installed the same image (SE2). We must install the EE2 image instead where the partitioning option is enabled by default.

Please have a look at this issue: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/597#issuecomment-335654741

Use this image: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase and use the EE2 (not SE2).

Thanks

Comment: I'm using store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1 and partition option is also disabled on it

Comment: I use database-enterprise:12.2.0.1 and partition option is also disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use this other docker image for Oracle 12c

https://hub.docker.com/r/tbparrish/oracle-12c